# Crystal Report Concatenate

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports

I'm trying to print a batch of Invoice's out then concatenate all the invoice numbers that are for the same customer in the batch.

This is the formula I'm using:

Group Header:
    shared stringvar b;
    b := '';

Group Detail:

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared stringvar b;
if not IsNull({INVCHEAD.LegalNumber}) then
(
 if (b = '') then
     b :=  b + {INVCHEAD.LegalNumber}       
 else
     b :=  b + ', ' + {INVCHEAD.LegalNumber}
)
```

Group Footer:

```
shared stringvar b;
b
```

As a result I have the invoice number on that page 70 times, not the other invoice numbers that are on the other 69 pages?

Any help will be appreciated,

Many Thanks

Comment: I don't see any mistake in the code. One thing that struck me is where did you place it in the report?

Comment: The Group header for the Customer ID Group, the details then the Group Footer?

Comment: Try to create another group `{INVCHEAD.LegalNumber}` inside customer ID group and then concatenate.